# Browsers load actual website from external server and keep in cache

Tags: html, web-development, javascript, cache, cache-control

So, currently, I'm using 000webhost to host my website, but they only allow 1000 MB to store all the files for my website, which IMO is a *little* small.

So, what I want to accomplish is something like this:

1. A new user goes to my site
2. Some kind of JS / HTML fetches the actual website from the server at my house, and stores the important bits in the browser's cache
3. The website is loaded entirely from cache, and is displayed and run normally

I'd also like some way to have an update function (e.g.: If I make a change to my website, it updates the file in the cache to the new version) and an error page in case the server goes down.

Comment: Is your web site just one page?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Exchange unfortunately. You're effectively asking for a tutorial rather than a single answer. I wish you good luck though. However, have you considered just putting your home server on a subdomain and loading resources from it from the main site?